# How come when I change an ENV variable and echo it in the same command, I don't see the new value?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

When I run `PATH=abc:$PATH echo $PATH`, I get the old value for `PATH`, not `abc:PATH`

Why is this? How can I get `abc:$PATH`?

Edit:
How about for `PATH=/mybin:$PATH which python` if `/mybin` has a python executable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run

```
PATH=abc:$PATH echo $PATH
```

or, in the more general case,

```
variable=value utility
```

then the `variable` is set in environment of the `utility` (but not in the current environment).

However, when your command line is parsed, the value of the `PATH` variable is taken from the *current* environment.

You would have to set the variable in the environment where the variable is expanded.  You may do this either either by separating it into two steps, as in

```
PATH=abc:$PATH; echo "$PATH"
```

which would set `PATH` in the current environment and *then* execute `echo "$PATH"`, or set the variable for a child shell, as in

```
PATH=abc:$PATH sh -c 'echo "$PATH"'
```

which would set the `PATH` variable within `sh -c`, but not in the current shell.

In your second example,

```
PATH=/mybin:$PATH which python
```

the `which` utility will probably say that `python` is found in `/mybin` since you modify `PATH` in its environment.  Notice how `PATH` is never expanded in the current environment here, but internally by `which`.

Incidentally, `which python` is better (more portably) written `command -v python` (see "[Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249)").

---

Just a quick reflection on your title, where you say "`ENV` variable".  The `ENV` variable, even if this was not what you meant, happens to be an environment variable that some implementations of `sh` (and some other shells) use.  If its value is the name of a file, that file will be sourced before starting an interactive shell session.  `bash` has a `BASH_ENV` variable which works the same way, but for non-interactive shells.

Comment: Whether parameters in the argument list are expanded in the parent or the child is an implementation detail and not required. What POSIX requires is that parameters in the argument list are expanded before the environment is set up. See explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the expansion for `echo $PATH` happens before the modified environment is created.

You may like to call:

```
PATH=abc:$PATH env
```

to see that the environment for the command indeed is modified.

Since the expansion of the echo argument in

```
PATH=abc:$PATH echo $PATH
```

happens before the new environment is set up, you need to split things up into two commands:

```
(PATH=abc:$PATH; echo $PATH)
```

does what you like. The sub shell () is needed to prevent the environment change to survive the lifetime of the `echo` command.

Answer (score 1):

Perform the substitution in a subshell instead of the current shell.

```
PATH=abc:$PATH sh -c 'echo $PATH'
```